# Регулярные выражения JAVA , как удалить символы из середины строки и конца строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Помогите кто знает **"регулярные выражения" .**

у меня есть метод , который чистит текст :

```
JSONObject clear (JSONObject input){
      String annotation = input.getString("annotation");
         Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("<br>$");     
         Matcher matcher = pattern1.matcher(annotation); 
      annotation = matcher.replaceAll("");   
      String text = input.getString("text");
         Matcher matcher2 = pattern1.matcher(text); 
      text = matcher2.replaceAll("");  
      input.put("annotation",annotation);
      input.put("text",text);
       return input;
   }
```

написал на него Юнит тест для проверки :

```
 @Test
   public void testOfClear () {
      JSONObject object= new JSONObject();
      object.put("annotation", "<....ки, накладні.<br/>\\n<br/>\\nCума&nbsp; не по.<br>");
      object.put("text", "<....ки, накладні.<br/>\\n<br/>\\nCума&nbsp; не по.<br>");
      JSONObject result = sign.clear(object);
      Assert.assertEquals("....ки, накладні.<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по..." , result.getString("annotation"));
      Assert.assertEquals("....ки, накладні.<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по..." , result.getString("text"));

   }
```

мне нужно:

в середине текста, если есть несколько новых строк подряд - нужно оставить только одну, так же
нужно удалить в конце текста полномочия `<br>` и пробелы.

пример:

**как было:**

```
....ки, накладні.<br/>\n<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по...<br>
```

**ожидаемый результат:**

```
....ки, накладні.<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по...
```

Вопрос , напишите как правильно комбинировать символы в РВ и желательно с примером, пробовал по всякому , не получается , либо только в конце удаляю либо в начале.

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("<br>$");
```

ломаю голову 2 сутки , любой ответ принимается , всем удачи с кодом!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найденное вот этим:

```
^((?:(?!\\n.*\\n)(?!<br>\s*$).)*)(?:\\n.*(\\n))?(.*?)(<br>\s*)?$
```

заменить вот этим:

```
$1$2$3
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5ad67

```
....ки, накладні.<br/>\n<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по...<br>
bwtboobrno
qqqq<br>
\n111
\n111\n222<br> \n333\n444<br> 
111<br>   <br><br> 
x\\n\\n<br<br>><br>
```

меняется на

```
....ки, накладні.<br/>\nCума&nbsp; не по...
bwtboobrno
qqqq
\n111
\n444
111<br>   <br>
x\\n<br<br>>
```

Сгенерированный код на Java:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^((?:(?!\\\\n.*\\\\n)(?!<br>\\s*$).)*)(?:\\\\n.*(\\\\n))?(.*?)(<br>\\s*)?$";
final String string = "....ки, накладні.<br/>\\n<br/>\\nCума&nbsp; не по...<br>\n"
     + "bwtboobrno\n"
     + "qqqq<br>\n"
     + "\\n111\n"
     + "\\n111\\n222<br> \\n333\\n444<br> \n"
     + "111<br>   <br><br> \n"
     + "x\\\\n\\\\n<br<br>><br>";
final String subst = "$1$2$3";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Comment: @dlm0n спасибо **большое** Вам, помогли!) только не совсем понятно зачем в TOOLS пишем `$1$2$3` ?

Comment: @StanislavPro `$i` означает "подставить значение i-ой группы", а регулярное выражение я специально написал так, чтобы 1, 2 и 3 группы вместе составляли искомый результат. Таким способом реализуется удаление всего ненужного, что находится не в этих группах

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1 = "....ки, накладні.<br/>\\n<br/>\\nCума&nbsp; не по...<br>";
String delete [] = {"\\n<br/>","<br>"};
s1 = replacementMass(s1,delete);
System.out.println(s1);


public static String replacementMass(String target, String ...x){
        String result = target;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i ++){
            result = new String(result.replace(x[i],""));
        }
        return result;
    }
```